# free web application to deploy on kubernetes with postgres backend

Tags: web-apps, postgresql, kubernetes

I am evaluating some of currently available kubernetes postgres-operators (cloudnativepg, zalando, crunchy etc.) For this evaluation, I also need a web application with postgres database on backend - for connecting to the cluster and perform benchmarking etc.

I appreciate if you recommend a few free web applications (or available for free trial) which are available for k8s deployment. Please post here to the project's Github page or deployment manifesto. Thanks.